# Java folder in android project and the src is empty

Tags: android

I found a library on git. https://github.com/flavienlaurent/NotBoringActionBar

after imported to the eclipse, I noticed that the src folder is empty and there is a folder called java. Tried to run it anyway but it gave me an error.

Do I have to make some changes before running it?

Comment: If the src folder is empty it means there is no java files in project, so you can't run that project.

Answer (score 5):

The project you are trying to import is developed with Android studio, so there is some extra files in it.

1. To import it in your eclipse you need to import it as normal android project. now your src folder is empty and you have an extra folder named java
2. copy com package from java folder and paste it in src folder
3. Delete java and bin folder
4. Clean and build your project
5. Run on emulator or device

Comment: I created a folder called "com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar" in src, put all those java in it. Clean and rebuild the project. Now there is an error in "package com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar;" of those java. Did I miss something?

Comment: you have changed package name so please update package name in manifest and all references of it too or use default package

Comment: But the package name in manifest is also com.flavienlaurent.notboringactionbar in this case.

Comment: have you changed import <packagename> in each of your activity. If you still get the error pleas paste your logcat. Basically you didn't need to create any folder in your src folder. just copy com folder from java folder and paste in src folder

Comment: Thank you, it works now just by copying the whole "com" folder. I made the com.xx.xxxx folder myself maybe this is why it caused the error!

Answer (score 0):

The Project you are trying to import is a project based on Gradle build system developed using Android Studio.

In such project everything related to code is in App/src/main

- /java contains all .java files
- /res  same as res in eclipse
- AndroidManifest.xml

So easiest solution is create a new project in eclipse and copy paste the file accordingly, 
In you case

1. Copy the src/com directory in /src in eclipse
2. Copy the /res in to /res directory of created project
3. Replace AndroidManifest.xml

But it is strongly recommended to migrate from Eclipse to Android Studio  instead of doing all these because now all the libraries available are migrating in to gradle.